# Visual Studio Crashing on static constructor in single file... [VS2010]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crash

I have a file, Mineral.cs, and whenever I try to replace the method InitializeMinerals() with a static constructor Visual Studio crashes. This reoccurs over and over each time after restarting. What?!

Error Reports from Event Log:

Event 1000, Application Error:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1fab3
Faulting module name: cslangsvc.dll, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba20c61
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0024b651
Faulting process id: 0x1904
Faulting application start time: 0x01d012904f2726d1
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll
Report Id: f146768b-7f33-11e4-80e9-083e8e5a419a
```

Event 1001, Windows Error Reporting:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 10.0.30319.1
P3: 4ba1fab3
P4: cslangsvc.dll
P5: 10.0.30319.1
P6: 4ba20c61
P7: c0000005
P8: 0024b651
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\CLASSIFIED\AppData\Local\debuggee.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\CLASSIFIED\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_devenv.exe_df1fb0912a591be97726252b29e971ef71bcbe74_0737cf24

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: f146768b-7f33-11e4-80e9-083e8e5a419a
Report Status: 0
```

Code in file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.Content.Items
{
    public class Mineral
    {


        public static void InitalizeMinerals()
        {

        }



        public Mineral(bool gem, string name, string[] subtypes = default(string[]))
        {
            this.IsGem = gem;
            this.Subtypes = subtypes;
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public bool IsGem
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string[] Subtypes
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }



   }
}
```

Comment: Show teh codes please.

Comment: You're probably better off submitting that error to MS Support. Have you tried a newer VS version?

Comment: Exactly when does it crash? When you compile? When you edit? When you look at the code?

Comment: When I replace  InitalizeMinerals() with "public static Mineral(){}"

Answer (score 0):

First, in C#, you can't have access modifiers on a static constructor.

Second, a little info about static constructors. They are used to initialize static data of the class, and are not called until just before the class is needed. So the first time you instantiate the Mineral class is when the static constructor is called. See this site for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Third, if you are creating an instance of your Mineral class in a Windows Form object in either the XXX_Load method or the constructor, then the Mineral static constructor will be called. Static constructors can play merry hob with your designer (and cause it to crash with strange errors). If you don't have to instantiate the Mineral class on Form creation/loading, don't. You can test to see if this is the case by simply commenting out the code that creates/relies on the Mineral class in your form and then trying the designer again. If no exception, then the static constructor for the Mineral class was probably throwing an exception when the designer tried to load the class. This kind of error usually only affects the designer, and the program can run perfectly fine.